# A problem with jQuery draggable with a selector handle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I have a problem where I have code like

```
<table id="table">
<tr>
<td>...</td>
<tr>
</tr>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and JavaScript such that

```
$('#table').draggable(handle: '#table > tr:eq(0) > td:eq(0)');
```

but for some reason the entire table becomes the handle. It works when I set the td to have an identifier, but does not seem to work with selectors. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
$('#table').draggable({handle: 'tr:first > td:first'});
```

It looks for the handler *inside* the specified element.

Comment: Damn man it worked! It works when I don't apply the element itself (#table) into the selector!